# MAC address of the sender of a DatagramPacket

Tags: java, java-native-interface, netty

Is it possible to get the MAC address of the sender of a `DatagramPacket` in Netty without using ARP?

I know that Java doesn't expose the layer 2 frame (which does contain the MAC addresses) however I expect there may be a way to do it via JNI?

Answer (score 0):

To make it short we do not support it in Netty atm. There may be ways to support it in the native transports in the future tho.

Comment: no... that said you could add support by yourself and send a pr to netty with the change.

Comment: Could you provide me a direction e.g. a file to look at?

Comment: I guess it would need to go into netty_epoll_linuxsocket.c and the related java class.